# How to select data inside a tile?

Tags: openstreetmap, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I have an OpenStreetMap PostGIS database and would like to select specific data (for example all shops) of each tile (on a defined zoomlevel) on the planet. Is this possible to achieve and if yes, how?

Comment: you need to retrieve vector data from postgis not raster - if your osm data is vector you can filter the subtype.

Comment: I am sorry, but I'm a beginner to PostGIS. Could you maybe explain step by step what I have to do and point me to the documentation I should read? Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Retrieve data in POSTGIS:**

You need to import OSM vector data and then using postgis and qgis (Qauntum GIS) you can visualise your query results

PostGIS retrieval of amenity

```
SELECT amenity, name
FROM osm.osm_point
Group by amenity, name
ORDER BY amenity DESC
```

http://gfoss.sigaberto.org/?tag=osm-postgis